# Behavior difference of lambda function mutable capture from a reference to global variable

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer

I found the results are different across compilers if I use a lambda to capture a reference to global variable with mutable keyword and then modify the value in the lambda function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

int n = 100;

std::function<int()> f()
{
    int &m = n;
    return [m] () mutable -> int {
        m += 123;
        return m;
    };
}

int main()
{
    int x = n;
    int y = f()();
    int z = n;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

Result from VS 2015 and GCC (g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609):

```
100 223 100
```

Result from clang++ (clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)):

```
100 223 223
```

Why does this happen? Is this allowed by the C++ Standards?

Comment: Clang's behavior is still present on trunk.

Comment: These are all rather old compiler versions

Comment: It still presents on recent version of Clang: https://godbolt.org/z/P9na9c

Comment: If you remove the capture entirely, then GCC still accepts this code and does what clang does. That's a strong hint that there's a GCC bug - simple-captures are not supposed to change the meaning of the lambda body.

Answer (score 15):

A lambda can't capture a reference *itself* by value (use `std::reference_wrapper` for that purpose).

In your lambda, `[m]` captures `m` by value (because there is no `&` in the capture), so `m` (being a reference to `n`) is first dereferenced and a *copy* of the thing it is referencing (`n`) is captured. This is no different than doing this:

```cpp
int &m = n;
int x = m; // <-- copy made!
```

The lambda then modifies that copy, not the original.  That is what you are seeing happen in the VS and GCC outputs, as expected.

The Clang output is wrong, and should be reported as a bug, if it hasn't already.

If you want your lambda to modify `n`, capture `m` by reference instead: `[&m]`. This is no different than assigning one reference to another, eg:

```cpp
int &m = n;
int &x = m; // <-- no copy made!
```

Or, you can just get rid of `m` altogether and capture `n` by reference instead: `[&n]`.

Although, since `n` is in global scope, it really doesn't need to be captured at all, the lambda can access it globally without capturing it:

```
return [] () -> int {
    n += 123;
    return n;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I think Clang may actually be correct.

According to [[lambda.capture]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#capture-11), an *id-expression* used in the lambda refers to the lambda's by-copy-captured member only if it constitutes an *odr-use*. If it doesn't, then it refers to the *original entity*. This applies to all C++ versions since C++11.

According to C++17's [[basic.dev.odr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#def.odr-3) a reference variable is not odr-used if applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to it yields a constant expression.

In the C++20 draft however the requirement for the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is dropped and the relevant passage changed multiple times to include or not include the conversion. See [CWG issue 1472](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1472) and [CWG issue 1741](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1741), as well as open [CWG issue 2083](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2083).

Since `m` is initialized with a constant expression (referring to a static storage duration object), using it yields a constant expression per exception in [[expr.const]/2.11.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.11.1).

This is not the case however if lvalue-to-rvalue conversions are applied, because the value of `n` is not usable in a constant expression.

Therefore, depending on whether or not lvalue-to-rvalue conversions are supposed to be applied in determining odr-use, when you use `m` in the lambda, it may or may not refer to the member of the lambda.

If the conversion should be applied, GCC and MSVC are correct, otherwise Clang is.

You can see that Clang changes it behavior if you change the initialization of `m` to not be a constant expression anymore:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

int n = 100;

void g() {}

std::function<int()> f()
{
    int &m = (g(), n);
    return [m] () mutable -> int {
        m += 123;
        return m;
    };
}

int main()
{
    int x = n;
    int y = f()();
    int z = n;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case all compilers agree that the output is

```
100 223 100
```

because `m` in the lambda will refer to the closure's member which is of type `int` copy-initialized from the reference variable `m` in `f`.

Comment: Are both of VS/GCC & Clang results correct? Or only one of them?

Comment: [basic.dev.odr]/3 says the variable `m` is odr-used by an expression naming it unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to it would be a constant expression. By [expr.const]/(2.7), that conversion would not be a core constant expression.

Comment: If Clang's result is correct, I think it's somehow counterintuitive. Because from programmer's point of view, he need to make sure the variable he write in the capture list actually being copied for mutable case, and the initialization of m might be changed by programmer later for some reason.

Comment: @aschepler I am honestly not exactly sure, but this is how Clang seems to see it. The paragraph was changed multiple times and I don't know for sure under which cases the lvalue-to-rvalue conversions are supposed to be considered.

Comment: @aschepler It seems that the conversion is not supposed to apply to references although the text seems to indicate it, see [CWG issue 2083](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2083) and [CWG issue 2103](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2103). Before resolution of [CWG issue 1741](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1741) the conversion wans't even mentioned and it seems to be an accident that it is worded to apply here.

Comment: I think your conclusion is correct for the current C++20 draft. Which seems unintentional, if `[m]` and `[&m]` do exactly the same thing if `m` is "usable in constant expressions" but different things otherwise.

Comment: Surely capturing by-copy of a name declared as reference should be the same as capturing by-copy the object the reference designates?  I think we can conclude from the CWG issues you list that there is noted discrepancy between wording and intent .  (and I think the C++17 wording supports the gcc behaviour, since lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `m` yields a non-constant expression)

Comment: Also, this interpretation would break the symmetry of references (e.g. at file scope, `int n = 100; int&m = n;` should have exactly the same semantics as `int m = 100; int &n = m;`)

Comment: @M.M I am still trying to figure out whether or not the odr-use is intended or not in this case, but see e.g. [here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34865#c3) a comment by Richard Smith indicating that it is not an odr-use.

Comment: @walnut f it's not deemed an odr-use then I would consider the text in expr.prim.lambda.capture to be defective instead

Comment: `m += 123;` Here `m` is odr-used.

Comment: @Oliv Whether it is, is exactly the question. You can decide to what object `m` refers at compile-time, so it doesn't really seem that the reference `m` would be odr-used. This is also the interpretation that e.g. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) uses: "*a reference is odr-used if it is used and its referent is not known at compile time;*". And in terms of the standard quotes, it seems to depend on the exact version you take, e.g. the wording in the resolution of CWG 1472, then it seems clearly not odr-used.

Comment: I think Clang is right by the current wording, and although I haven't dug into this, the relevant changes here are almost certainly all DRs.

Comment: You say "a reference variable is not odr-used if applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to it yields a constant expression." But lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to the id-expression 'm' is not a constant expression. If it were the case, a declaration such as 'constexpr int x = m' in the body of 'f' would compile.

Comment: You can even check clang message: [here](https://godbolt.org/z/UrnhsR).

Comment: @Oliv Yes, I agree. What I am trying to say is that *if* lvalue-to-rvalue conversion should be applied as part of the "*is constant expression*" test, then the use of `m` is not a constant expression and therefore an odr-use, but if this conversion should not be considered, then the use of `m` is a constant expression and therefore not an odr-use. Which of the two is supposed to be right, I don't know, as described in the linked issues, the wording of the odr-use rules changed multiple times, e.g. I guess the C++17 wording requires it, but the current C++20 draft does not.

Comment: @Oliv In the use `constexpr int x = m;` the test is not for whether or not `m` is odr-used, but for whether or not the whole intialization of `x` is a constant expression, which always includes the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, independently of the odr-use rule.

Comment: @walnut Sorry, I did not grasp the heart of your answer were the historic evolution of the standard.

Answer (score 4):

This is not allowed by the C++17 Standard, but by some other Standard drafts it might be. It's complicated, for reasons not explained in this answer.

[[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10):

> For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified. The type of such a data member is the referenced type if the entity is a reference to an object, an lvalue reference to the referenced function type if the entity is a reference to a function, or the type of the corresponding captured entity otherwise.

The `[m]` means that the variable `m` in `f` is captured by copy. The entity `m` is a reference to object, so the closure type has a member whose type is the referenced type. That is, the member's type is `int`, and not `int&`.

Since the name `m` inside the lambda body names the closure object's member and not the variable in `f` (and this is the questionable part), the statement `m += 123;` modifies that member, which is a different `int` object from `::n`.